# Why is analysis called "analysis"?

Tags: real-analysis, soft-question, terminology, math-history

Just as the topic says, how did the name "analysis" come to denote the specific mathematical branch dealing with limits and stuff? The term "analysis" seems very generic compared to the words for the other two main branches, "algebra" and "geometry", which do not seem to have other unrelated meanings.

Comment: Algebra in a broad sense is the study of system of symbols and rules for manipulating these symbols. In what world is this not a generic term?

Comment: I guess the OP means that *analysis* literally just means *resolving*, a very generic concept. I recall a similar question here regarding *calculus*; there the confusion was caused by the fact that this is just short for *differential calculus*. I don't think anything like that (e.g. *differential analysis*) was ever in use, but see the distinction from *functional analysis* and also *analysis situs* (today called topology)

Comment: I always thought it took its name from analytic functions.

Comment: @Doop, the term "analysis" was being used in this sense *before* the notion of "function" was introduced, and certainly *long* before the notion of "analytic function" was introduced.

Comment: I've never heard the term *analysis* being used by itself as a topic like that, only phrases like *Linear Analysis*.

Answer (score 13):

There is a tradition on early modern mathematics regarding the usage of the term *analysis* :

- François Viète, *Isagoge in Artem Analyticem* (Introduction to the Analytic Art), Tours, 1591 (several successive editions and translations);
- Thomas Harriot, *Artis Analyticae Praxis*, London, 1631.

The background is the "rediscovery" of ancient Greek mathematics and, in particular of [Pappus of Alexandria](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pappus_of_Alexandria), (c.A.D. 290 – c.350) and his main work in eight books titled *Synagoge* or *Collection*, which **Book VII** explains the terms analysis and synthesis, and the distinction between theorem and problem.

See Henk Bos, *Redefining Geometrical Exactness. Descartes' Transformation of the Early Modern Concept of Construction* (2001), page :

> Two kinds of analysis were distinguished in early modern geometry: the classical and the algebraic. The former method was known from examples in classical mathematical texts in which the constructions of problems were preceded by an argument referred to as "analysis;" in those cases the constructions were called "synthesis".

Reference to Pappus' problems is also found into René Descartes' [La Géométrie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_G%C3%A9om%C3%A9trie) (1637).

The two main line to be understood are :

- analysis as a "method" to solve problem
- analysis as the technique of treating geometrical problems with algebraic methods.

Both, I think, are "involved" into the use of analysis to name the new method introduced by Newton and Leibniz.

You can see :

> Jaakko Hintikka & U.Remes, [The Method of Analysis: Its Geometrical Origin and Its General Significance](http://books.google.it/books/about/The_Method_of_Analysis.html?id=zEb7PjUzZqsC&redir_esc=y) 
>    (1974)

and :

> Michael Otte & Marco Panza, [Analysis and Synthesis in Mathematics: History and Philosophy](http://books.google.it/books/about/Analysis_and_Synthesis_in_Mathematics.html?id=WFav-N0tv7AC&redir_esc=y) (1997).

Comment: Very nice references. It looks like you thought of the analysis/synthesis distinction a bit. If you are familiar with Fermat's two derivations of the least time principle in optics, I would appreciate hearing why you think he called them respectively "analysis" and "synthesis" as I only have a vague understanding of this.

Comment: THe issue is "complicated" because dates back to Greek math (I'm not very familiar with it) and the Renaissance discovery of (the heritage of) Greek math. One of the "threads" was the (partly misconceived) convinction that there were hidden in some Greek book a "method" (sse Archimedes) for the *discovery* of the solution of math problems: this was the analytical side, compared to the exposition of the theorem in axiomatic form typical of Greek masterpieces (Euclid's Elements): this was the Synthetic side. During Renaissance there were a lot of debate both in philosophy and math. 1/2

Comment: I think can be useful Bos's book, Paolo Mancosu, [Philosophy of Mathematics and Mathematical Practice in the Seventeenth Century](http://www.amazon.com/Philosophy-Mathematics-Mathematical-Practice-Seventeenth/dp/0195132440/ref=la_B001H6Q58M_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1399626534&sr=1-1) (1999) and Jacob Klein, [Greek Mathematical Thought and the Origin of Algebra](http://www.amazon.com/Mathematical-Thought-Origin-Algebra-Mathematics/dp/0486272893/ref=sr_1_3?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1399626590&sr=1-3&keywords=jacob+klein) (1932 - Dover reprint). 2/3

Comment: Descartes is (for me) a "big player" in this issue, both for his mathematical innovation (that must be read as a method for the "discovery" of the solution of geometrical problems) **and** for his philosophical backround regarding *method* (see the unpublished *Regulae ad directionem ingenii* (1626–1628): see Rule five). I do not know about Fermat's optics, but I think this background may help. 3/3

Comment: Do you know about Michael Mahoney, *The Mathematical Career of Pierre de Fermat* (1973) ?  There are some pages dedicated to *optics* (pages 387-402).

Comment: I think that Fermat's analysis in optics is related to the derivation of the law of refraction with modern "analytical" (i.e. *calculus* in the modern term) tools; then he want to present them in "official" setting: i.e.according to Greek geometrical way. See page 400 : "Fermat felt the necessity of providing a synthetic demonstration of a result achieved by his analytic use of the method of maxima and minima."

Comment: Mauro, I understand that, and I saw that phrase, but I don't really understand in what sense a proof using Euclidean geometry is a synthetic proof. I know what synthetic means in projective geometry, but here the meaning seems a bit more obscure.

Comment: @user72694 - you are right: today it is obscure. You must go back to Pappus and Renaissance phil. The terms have little to do with modern math. Analysis is used to mean: analyze a problem in order to find tghe condition to be fulfileld to solve it. Synthesis is more : deduce a theorem form first principles. The "new" analytical method used by Fermat was "perceived" as a technique devoided of sound "foundations" (see the problem of $x=x+dx$ in l'Hopital) and an "euclidean" proof of the law of refraction was needed in order to "legitimize" the result.

Comment: @user72694 - I'mm alluding to your [post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/776050/lhopitals-questionable-premise) regarding l'Hopital; my refernce is that in order to understand Fermat's double proof, we have to study the context. Half a century before the first "systhematization" (l'Hopital textbook) there were confidence about the power of "infinitesimal" method, but at the same time difficulties in justifying its soundness; thus the usage (by Fermat and others) as a tool for discovery the solution of a problem (analysis) to be supplemented by a "regular" proof of it (synthesis).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Actually, whether or not Fermat used infinitesimals is an interesting issue and the subject of a scholarly dispute. We have a recent publication on this [here](http://www.mitpressjournals.org/doi/abs/10.1162/POSC_a_00101).

Comment: @user72694 - you are a professional historian of math ! I've found some of your papers; I'll read with interest the one regarding IS MATHEMATICAL HISTORY WRITTEN BY THE VICTORS ? It remember me Kuhn's book about *SciRevs*. My "perception" in the above discussion is shaped by Kuhn (I've read it a lot of years ago and I'm still thinking it is illuminating). With l'Hopital textbook we see the "victory" of the new generation (allez en avant et la fois vous viendra ...) which is "accustomed" with the leibnizian formalism... 1/2

Comment: From Archimedes to Fermat all "infinitistic" methods were subject to criticism because lacking of foundation: thus the need to use them for discovery and then to "hide them". With l'Hopital generation (I guess) we see that professional mathematicians are nor more concerned with the lacking of foundations (I think that all good math were aware of the problem of **writing** something like $x=x+dx$ and at the same time **assuming** that $dx \ne 0$ ...) but ... it works and the "old" generation "blocked" by the concern with synthetic proofs has gone. 2/2

Comment: @user72694 - about Fermat and infinitesimals ... sorry for my sloppiness. I'm not a professional historian and thus I'm not alluding to a certainity about that issue. I'm using infinitesimals in a wrong way to mean all "infinirìtistic" methods used in that age : Fermat, Cavalieri, Wallis, and so on.

Answer (score 9):

The first occurrence (1696) of the term "analysis" in the sense of the mathematical discipline extending calculus occurs in the title of l'Hopital's work [Analyse des Infiniment Petits pour l'Intelligence des Lignes Courbes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analyse_des_Infiniment_Petits_pour_l%27Intelligence_des_Lignes_Courbes). The term had been used earlier as part of a dichotomy analysis/synthesis, for example in Fermat. However l'Hopital was the first to use the term to describe the new science being created by Leibniz and others in the 17th century.